# Showing a single node and all associated comments in Drupal 6 Views 2

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-views

I am trying to create a view on Drupal 6 (views 2) that simply displays the latest node of a specific type and all of the associated comments from that node.

I am sure that there is a simple method to do this that I just don't know.

Algorithmically, I would solve it by ascertaining the latest node of the type and then recursing through all its children. But I can't apparently do that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Good news! This is not so hard. :)

Create a view that you will use as your front page. Have it grab and display the single node that you want along with it's comments. Then, under filter, pick node: Post Date and do greater than -1 and less than +1 days.

Here's an example:

Basic settings
Name: Defaults
Title: None
Style: Unformatted
Row style: Fields
Use AJAX: No
Use pager: No
Items to display: 1
More link: No
Distinct: No
Access: Unrestricted
Caching: None
Exposed form in block: No
Header: None
Footer: None
Empty text: None
CSS class: None
Theme: Information

--

Relationships
None defined

--

Arguments
None defined

--

Fields
Node: Title Title
Node: Post date Post date
Node: Body
Node: Last comment time Last comment time
Node: Add comment link Add comment
Node: Comment count Comment count
Comment: Title
Comment: Author Author
Comment: Body

--
Sort criteria
None defined

--

Filters
Node: Post date > -1 day
Node: Post date